# How to copy and paste selected text in nano on a Mac?

Tags: mac, nano

I’m using [`nano`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nano.1.html) in [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com), I can mark the text using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> but I'm not able to copy and paste the text. I know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> can be used cut the entire line. What is the keyboard shortcut for copying only marked text in `nano`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Set the mark to start highlighting the text :
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
2. Copy the highlighted text: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
3. Paste the text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Note: Your meta key should mapped to the Option / Alt key (by default it would be mapped to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in case of iTerm.

On iTerm, you can do this by going to `Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `Keys` and set Left option key and Right option key to `Esc+`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @shaahiin 's answer, if you are using a Mac keyboard, try Esc + 6 instead of Option + 6 and Option + Shift + 6 instead. The meta key (indicated by M in nano) is Esc on Mac.

Comment: This is what did it for me, thanks Zahra!

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> shortcut to copy selected

Comment: And what about paste?

Answer (score 0):

I know no keystroke for it but you could cut it with CTRL-K and then paste it with CTRL-U at the same position. Afterwards you can go to the desired position and paste it again with CTRL-U. Or if you just want to copy it to another program, you can mark text an use cmd+shift+C to get it into the clipboard. To mark text you can use ctrl+^ and then you can use your arrow-keys to mark text.

I've wrote an article about this for Linux / MacOSX on my blog:
https://www.ask-sheldon.com/deleting-multiple-lines-with-nano/

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, and the question indicates that SG_ already knows how to cut and paste entire lines and how to mark text.

Comment: Why? I told him how to work around the problem! Do you see a CTRL-U in his question? Or do you have a better answer?